# Trouble with OpenGL VBOs and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl

I'm starting OpenGL and instead of manually binding buffers, I tried making a function to do it for me but I'm getting these 2 error.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl createArrayBuffer(float *,unsigned int *,unsigned int)" (?createArrayBuffer@@YAXPAMPAII@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Example::init(void)" (?init@Example@@QAE_NXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl bindAndPoint(unsigned int *,int)" (?bindAndPoint@@YAXPAIH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Example::render(void)" (?render@Example@@QAEXXZ)
```

I think this has to do with pointers being sort of confusing to me. Here's the code.

BufferUtilities.cpp:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_EXTRA_LEAN

#include <windows.h>

#include "BufferUtilities.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gl\GLU.h>

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL+(i))

bool start()
{
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");

    if (!glGenBuffers || !glBindBuffer || !glBufferData)
    {
        std::cerr << "Vertex buffer objects are not supported by your graphics card." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

inline void createArrayBuffer(GLfloat *array, GLuint *buffer, GLenum usage)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])), &array[0], usage);
}

inline void bindAndPoint(GLuint *buffer, int size)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *buffer);
    glColorPointer(size, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
}
```

BufferUtilities.h

```
#pragma once

#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLEXT.h>

static PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC glGenBuffers = NULL;
static PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC glBindBuffer = NULL;
static PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC glBufferData = NULL;

bool start();

inline void createArrayBuffer(GLfloat *array, GLuint *buffer, GLenum usage);

inline void bindAndPoint(GLuint *buffer, int size);
```

The two functions that use the functions above

```
void Example::render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    bindAndPoint(&colorBuffer, 3);

    bindAndPoint(&vertexBuffer, 3);

    //Translates the zPosition before rendering
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, zPosition);

    //Draws the square as a triangle strip
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
bool Example::init()
{
    if (!start())
    {
        return false;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    GLfloat verticies[] = {
        -2.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f,
        2.0f, -2.0f, -2.0f,
        -2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f,
        2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f,
    };

    GLfloat colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    createArrayBuffer(verticies, &vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    createArrayBuffer(colors, &colorBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    //Return success
    return true;
}
```

Removing inline from both functions lets it compile, but a new error appears at run time at glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4). It is

```
Unhandled exception at 0x697655D5 (nvoglv32.dll) in Chapter 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I checked if all of the pointers were NULL, and they aren't. I also checked to see if init() and start() return true, and they do.

Comment: Move the definition of `createArrayBuffer` to the header file, or remove the keyword `inline` from it.

Comment: Use a debugger to get to the offending line.

Comment: Another thing: *Never* use the availability of function pointers through wglGetProcAddress as a feature support indicator. OpenGL implementations may give you the function pointers even if a certain feature is not supported. Case in point for example when Buffer Objects were just extensions and not yet core functionality Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs) and Pixel Buffer Objects (PBOs) were different features, but reused the `gl…Buffer` functions. **Always** check the GL_EXTENSION string for supported features.

Comment: +1 to @datenwolf - I remember some implementation returning non-null pointers even on some gibberish function names that surely don't exist (it was on android, as I recall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `inline` keyword. Remove it from both the function definitions and prototypes and the code should compile. E.g.:

```
void createArrayBuffer(GLfloat *array, GLuint *buffer, GLenum usage);
void bindAndPoint(GLuint *buffer, int size);
```

In `BufferUtilities.h` and `BufferUtilities.cpp`

When you declare a function as `inline`, you must put the declaration and the definition in the same file. Usually a header file. Take a further look at the concept by reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) and [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson13.html) links.

As for the runtime error, it seems like one of the pointer you are passing to the functions is null.
It is a good practice to add some checks to pointer parameters when you use them. E.g.:

```
#include <assert.h>

void createArrayBuffer(GLfloat *array, GLuint *buffer, GLenum usage)
{
    assert(array != NULL);
    assert(buffer != NULL);
    ...
}
```

The `assert`s will help you pinpoint the error by halting program execution and calling the debugger if one of the pointers is null.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least 3 problems:

1. `inline`, obviously. Already stated and explained. Next.
2. 0xC0000005 very likely means you're calling function with NULL address. Check if your `start` and `Engine::init` functions returning `true`.
3. `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])), &array[0], usage);` What is size, again?.. `typeof(array) == GLfloat*`, => `typeof(array[0]) == GLfloat`, => size is `sizeof(GLfloat*) / sizeof(GLfloat)`, which is 1 on 32bit x86 OS and 2 on 64bit - in both cases it is incorrect.

Comment: E.g. by passing size (or at least elements count) as separate function argument.

Comment: I fixed it by using a vector